# Dialogflow to Actions on Google: Request contains an invalid argument

Tags: action, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

Request contains an invalid argument.
The query pattern '$SchemaOrg_Date:date' contains an undefined parameter (name: 'date' type: 'SchemaOrg_Date')

No idea what happened to my dialogflow.It gives me the error and no idea where to look for SchemaOrg_Date and date

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Found it within one of 200 Intents!

The intent had a parameter @date-period

As User says, we had Yesterday which dialogflow did not select it as @date-period but @date

Do not look on your Json(s), you need to manually find it on your Intents.

Answer (score 0):

I was setting an entity slot to a 'required' value, which caused it to fail, if I didn't provide a hard coded Response in Dialogflow for the required value.

Answer (score 0):

This might help sombody :

In your dialogflow, if you have different langages, be careful to chose the good one in your api and for this problem, to check the intents of the other langages versions, the intents you created are not the same everywhere !
for exemple : if you created intents in the langage en-us and en-gb, you need to check the intents on both.
Took the night to find that out. and i don't agree with user2793508, you can find the entity by doing a research on your json files, that's how i knew where to look and when i didn't see it, i checked the other langages just per curiosity, that saved me, lol.

Hope i was clear, see ya

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but it is resolved now.
There was a problem in the intent as the **Training phrases** was not assigned to the given 
 **Action and parameters**
there the multiple copies of the same Parameter was created.

Example : *John* wants a flower

name - "John"
name - "   "

two parameters with same name will create the error 
remove the one without any use or self created one and the error will be removed.

or assign the keyword by double clicking them to the preferred parameter in **Training phrases** .